# Definite integral of a continuous function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $f(1)=5$ and $f(3)=11$\
If $g(x)=\displaystyle\int_1^3{f(x+t)dt}$ then find $g'(0)$\
Using the definition of $g'(0)$ if I proceed,$g'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{1}{x}\big[\displaystyle\int_1^3{f(x+t)dt}-\displaystyle\int_1^3{f(t)dt}\big]$\
I am unable to proceed because I can not apply mean value theorem.  Also the rule of differentiation under integral sign does not lead me anywhere.Please help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For a fixed $x$, put

$$u=x+t$$

the function becomes

$$g(x)=\int_{x+1}^{x+3}f(u)du$$

$$=F(x+3)-F(x+1)$$
with

$$F(X)=\int_0^Xf(u)du.$$

$f$ is continuous at $\Bbb R$, thus
$$F'(X)=f(X)$$

You will find that
$$g'(0)=f(0+3)-f(0+1)=6$$

Comment: There are two variables x and t. Putting u=t+x how do you justify du=dt. What about dx?